# Guidelines for writing Julia code future-compatible with v0.4

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia, and I am in the process of porting code from other languages.  I am using Julia included in the latest WinPython (beta), which is v0.3.5.  From this link, it appears that v0.4 will be released in the next couple of months:
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/milestones

As much as possible, I would like to avoid having to modify code written for v0.3.5 when later running in a v0.4 environment.  I found this code that gives me some clues about deprecations in v0.4:
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/deprecated.jl

Using it, I started this list of coding guidelines:

- Avoid using ifloor(), iceil(), iround() and itrunc() functions.
- Use throw() instead of error().
- Use parseint() and parsefloat() for conversions from strings.
- Begin functions that convert to a type with upper case.
- Use flipdim(A,1) instead of flipud(A).
- Use flipdim(A,2) instead of fliplr(A).

Please expand on this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite possible that there will be a change before release that affects you that will make it impossible to support both. Of the easier fixes, [Compat.jl should handle a majority](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl).

Comment: The full list of things to change should be in NEWS.md: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md